# Hosting a SQLITE database file on AWS

Tags: node.js, sqlite, file, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a **node application** which uses **SQLite** as a **database**. I am going to host my application on **AWS EC2**, and I am wondering if I can just upload the SQLITE database there as well with the rest of the files, as it is just a file or do I need to store that separately in a **storage** like **S3** for example ? And what **AMI** to choose if it is possible to host it with the rest of the files on **EC2** ?

Comment: Do you plan to install and use mysql in your AWS RC2-instance ? If so then you need to create a database and install the database-schema into the newly created database of your mysql-instance.

Comment: no, I don't plan to use mysql.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question. Since SQLite is a file-based database, you can upload your SQLite-database and it should work. There is no need to use S3.
I recommed using an AMI, which has node.js already installed, for example: **Node.js basic machine**

Comment: thank's. I cannot see Node.js basic machine under EC2 AMI-s. However I used Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type before but I needed to install node.js. P.S I am not paying for AWS probbaly that's the reason.

Comment: You can use Amazon EFS volume and mount it to the EC2 where you store the SQL Lite files.

Comment: Go to EC2-Dashboard, click button *Launch Instance* and **Node.js basic machine** is located under tab *Community AMIs*. The **Node.js basic machine**  is community provided, so it is free of charge.